# Weird wrapping on review stats pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

A screen shot of the issue:

[image: Screen shot of issue]

The user names of the reviewers are being sent to the next line for whatever reason. This also seems to be happening on other sites in the Stack Exchange network as well.

Also let me know if I need to add a bunch of those red circles to the image to further highlight the issue.

Comment: Don't change it back, I like it ...

Comment: Needs more free-hand red circles.

Comment: Looks like it's cause due to a CSS width being too much on `.user-info .user-details`. Reduce it from 147px to 143px and it's OK, though I expect it was widened for somewhere else in the site.

Comment: This has also broken the revision pages; e.g http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34134540/revisions

Comment: I just go to review page, and see this behavior, and just going to post  question, but before click the "Post Question" button, I just search on Main page, and this question already asked. This behavior is on Meta and main SO site.

Comment: I also noticed this on the "responses" tab of my profile this morning.

Comment: Just taken a screenshot of the same issue as @Matt's report, but he's beaten me to it! Seen on Firefox 42.0/Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: MSE dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270459/review-queue-layout-shows-name-below-user-gravatar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be resolved in the latest build!

Comment: Looks fixed where I had seen it on the profile page ("responses") _except_ for "revisions" for me. [Actually, "revisions" on the "responses" tab looks even worse than before.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qCjJP.png)

Comment: @Kendra I'm not seeing that - do you have a link?

Comment: Yes ma'am. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2607247/kendra?tab=responses&sort=revisions Edit: I'm actually seeing odd badge wrapping in the "comments" tab of my profile as well, and it's even worse on main. I'm on Chrome 47.0.2526.73

Comment: @Kendra Welp, did you post a bug? :)

Comment: Working on it, getting a couple more screen shots since I saw a couple more, and different, examples. :)

Comment: @Kendra Fix coming soon for that

Comment: Cool. Do you want an actual bug report for that, or is it good without one.

Comment: @Kendra Should be fixed.